# Secure Wallet Architecture Ideas

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, private-key, architecture

I have been tasked with developing a wallet that can store Cryptocurrency and NFTs. I understand that cryptos and nfts are not actually stored in the wallet, but the private keys that are used to access them are. I now have to figure out a secure way to handle and store these keys. The stack I’m using is react-native with web3js and infura.

In my search for a secure solution I have come across the following ideas.

  **1 – Store Keys on the hardware**
  In this solution you simply store the private keys on your device. Whenever you need to perform a transaction you access them from your storage, sign the transaction and send it. The private keys never leave your mobile.
  The downside to this approach is if you break or lose your device, the private keys are gone forever because there is no backup.
  **2 – Encrypt Keys and store on a backend server**
  As the title suggests simply encrypt and store on a central db. But this doesn’t make it a very decentralized approach. Plus in this case you have to figure out if the transactions are gonna be signed from the front end or back end. If front end, then the keys will have to travel through an API call which isn’t very secure. Signing from the back end also poses its own risks.
  **3 – Store Keys on the blockchain**
  Someone mentioned this idea to me and I did not understand it correctly. It was something like you store the key on the chain itself (encrypted) and access it through a password or seed phrase. But the thought of the private key sitting on the chain itself scares me.
  **4 – Store Keys on a Smart Contract**
  Again mentioned by someone and I did not understand. Pretty similar to previous one.
  **5 -  Store Keys on SGX Nodes**
  This was mentioned by someone I know who are using it in production for their wallet. The basic idea is that the private key is divided into 8 different parts and stored on 8 different servers. For signing a tx, atleast 4 of the 8 parts are required to complete the private key.

I am lost in thought about how to go in with this. I want to implement a solution where the user has at the very least some degree of a backup in case of lost private keys. The other thing I’m thinking is whether I should let the user handle keys at all and instead handle it for them, like a custodial wallet.  My main concern here is security.

My appologies if this has been discussed before but I was unable to find anything related to wallet architecture.

The chain I am currently working with is Ethereum

Comment: curious to know if you found any answer/directions for the best approach. I am looking into something similar and am not sure which option would be the best.